# Whoops, something went wrong on our end

Tags: gitlab, cicd, gitlab-ce

we installed gitlab ce 14 on ubuntu 22.04
and everything looks good except some links
for example “/-/settings/ci_cd” (where we configure the variables)
we get the “500 Whoops, something went wrong on our end”.

we checked this file /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log and found this

```
Rendered layout layouts/project_settings.html.haml (Duration: 69.9ms | Allocations: 25155)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 182ms (ActiveRecord: 20.6ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms | Allocations: 44805)
  
ActionView::Template::Error ():
     9:       = render partial: 'ci/runner/setup_runner_in_aws',
    10:                locals: { registration_token: @project.runners_token }
    11:     %hr
    12:     = render partial: 'ci/runner/how_to_setup_runner',
    13:             locals: { registration_token: @project.runners_token,
    14:                       type: s_('Runners|specific'),
    15:                       reset_token_url: reset_registration_token_namespace_project_settings_ci_cd_path,
  
lib/gitlab/crypto_helper.rb:28:in 'aes256_gcm_decrypt'
app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encryption_helper.rb:18:in 'decrypt_token'
app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encrypted.rb:78:in 'get_encrypted_token'
app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encrypted.rb:117:in 'token_set?'
app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/base.rb:46:in 'ensure_token!'
app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable.rb:54:in 'block in add_authentication_token_field'
app/models/project.rb:1904:in 'runners_token'
app/views/projects/runners/_specific_runners.html.haml:12
app/views/projects/runners/_settings.html.haml:5
app/views/projects/settings/ci_cd/show.html.haml:48
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:142:in 'render'
app/controllers/projects/settings/ci_cd_controller.rb:34:in 'block in show'
lib/gitlab/database.rb:193:in 'allow_cross_joins_across_databases'
app/controllers/projects/settings/ci_cd_controller.rb:33:in 'show'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:520:in 'set_current_admin'
lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in 'with_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:511:in 'set_session_storage'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:105:in 'with_locale'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:111:in 'with_user_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:505:in 'set_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:499:in 'set_current_context'
lib/gitlab/metrics/elasticsearch_rack_middleware.rb:16:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:33:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/memory_report.rb:13:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/speedscope.rb:13:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:17:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/rack_middleware.rb:23:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in 'block in call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/web_transaction.rb:46:in 'run'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:19:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:21:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in 'block in call'
lib/gitlab/database/query_analyzer.rb:46:in 'within'
lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:173:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:50:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_malformed_strings.rb:21:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:21:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/webhook_recursion_detection.rb:15:in 'call'
config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:11:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/compressed_json.rb:26:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/rack_multipart_tempfile_factory.rb:19:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_web_static.rb:20:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:77:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:13:in 'call'
```

and when we run a pipeline we get this output
[image]

the pages with 500 error code work properly and the pipeline as well